# C# Fast Upload Related Tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am working on a dynamic loader.  Based on a database table that defines the flat text files I can read a single file with multiple record types and load it into database tables.  The tables are related and using identity primary keys.  Everything is currently working but runs really slow as would be expected given that it is all accomplished by single insert statements.  I am working on optimizing the process and cant find an 'easy' or 'best practice' answer on the web.

My current project deals with 8 tables but to simplify I will use a customers / orders example.

Lets look at two customers below, the data would repeat for each set of customers and orders in the data file.  Parent records are always before child records.  The first field is record type and each record type has a different definition of the fields that follow.  This is all specified in the control tables.

```
CUST|Joe Green|123 Main St
ORD|Pancakes|5
ORD|Nails|2
CUST|John Deere|456 Park Pl
ORD|Tires|4
```

Current code will:

- Insert customer Joe Green and return an ID.  (Using Output
  Inserted.Id in the insert statement)
- Insert orders pancakes and nails attaching the returned ID.
- Insert customer John Deere and return an ID.
- Insert order Tires with the return ID.

This runs painfully slow.  If this could be optimized and I wouldn't have to change much code, that would be ideal but I cant think of how.

So the solution?  I was thinking datatables...  Here is what I am thinking of so far.

- Create Transaction
- Lock all tables that are part of the 'file definition', in this case
  Customers and Orders Get max ID for each table and increment by one
  to have starting IDs for all tables
- Create datatable for all tables
- Execute as currently set up but instead of issuing insert statements 
  add to data table
- After data is read bulk upload tables in the correct order based on
  relationships
- Unlock tables
- End Transaction

I was wondering, before I go down this path, if anyone has worked out a better solution.  I am also considering a custom script component in SSIS.  I have seen posts and blogs about holding off on commiting a transaction but each parent record has only a few child records and the tree can get up to 4 deep, think order details and products.  Due to needing the parent record ID I need to commit the insert of parent records.  I have also considered managing the ID's myself rather than Identity but I do not want to add that extra management if I can avoid it.

UPDATE based on answer, for clarification / context.

A typical text file has

```
one file header record
- 5 facility records that relate to the file header
- 7,000 customers(account)
- 5 - 10 notes per customer
- 1-5 payments at the account level
- 1-5 adjustments at the account level
- 5 - 20 orders per customer
- 5 - 20 order details per order
- 1-5 payments at the order level
- 1-5 adjustments at the order level
- one file trailer record related to the file header



Keys
- File Header -> Facility -> Customer (Account)
- File Header -> FileTrailer
- Customer -> Notes
- Customer -> Payments
- Customer -> Adjustments
- Customer -> Orders
- Order -> OrderDetails
- Order -> Payments
- Order -> Adjustments
```

There are a few more tables involved but this should give an idea of the overall context.

```
Data Sample ... = MORE FIELDS .... MORE RECORDS
HEADER|F1|F2|...
FACILITY|F1|F2|..
CUSTOMER|F1|F2|...
NOTE|F1|F2|....
....
ORDER|F1|F2|...
ORDERDETAIL|F1|F2|...
.... ORDER DETAILS
ORDERPYMT|F1|F2|...
....
ORDERADJ|F1|F2|...
....
CUSTOMERPYMT|F1|F2|...
....
CUSTOMERADJ|F1|F2|...
....

(The structure repeats for each facility)

TRAILER|F1|F2|...
```

Comment: Why are You convinced you need to commit to get a recordID from a parent table?

Comment: Had a very similar situation to yours a few months ago, tried all the import methods (RBAR from Excel/CSV, regular SQL connections, etc.) and ended up going with `sqlbulkcopy`. As part of the process, sometimes it's necessary to add a column. To handle that, I create a new table (using SMO but that's not relevant) with the new definition, insert rows from old table, insert rows from new text file, rename new table, rename old table. There are surely other approaches but this is exponentially faster than doing individual inserts (especially if the definition changes).

Comment: @user6144226  I need to reserve the customer id to be used in the order inserts.  How can I ensure another process will not do an insert and take that customer id if I do not commit the customer insert?

Comment: @JacobH  My problem is that while I build data tables I need to manage the reservation of parent record ids.  I cant see how to do that if I need to do multiple bulk inserts on related tables.

Comment: Because when you insert into a table with an identity that value is consumed. It is consumed even if you have it inside a transaction and roll it back. The transaction here seems to be adding nothing but complexity and possible performance loss (although with such a small transaction it is unlikely).

Comment: What if you loaded your data into datatables and use a guid to identity the order header. Then use that same guid for the order lines. When you insert the order header you just need to update your datatable with the new identity value. Then you can tie those together easily with the order lines and insert those as a single insert also..

Comment: @SeanLange  I wasnt aware that identity and transactions work that way.  Very good to know, thank you.  The GUID approach to take advantage of the nature of GUID without having to use it as a primary key is very interesting, thank  you, I will have to think that through.

Comment: hehe yeah the identity is running number that increments on every attempted insert. As such it will have gaps when an insert fails. There are other gaps too but that is another topic entirely.

Comment: @SeanLange - the question clearly states that OP is using Max ID (+1) approach. Though I highly recommend switching to built-in identity.

Comment: @user6144226 can you share how you know they are using MAX(+1)?. They say "identity primary keys" and never mention using that horrific MAX(+1) anti-pattern.

Comment: @SeanLange my bad - I got the wrong idea from the Lock Table/ Get Max ID part.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting related tables with low data volumes should normally not be a problem. If they are slow, we will need more context to answer your question.

If you are encountering problems because you have many records to insert, you will probably have to look at [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx).
If you prefer not managing your ids yourself, the cleanest way I know of is working with temporary placeholder id columns.

- Create and fill datatables with your data and a tempId columns you fill yourself and foreign keys blank
- SqlBulkCopy primary table
- Update secondary datatable with generated foreign keys by finding primary keys from previously inserted table through your tempids column
- Upload secondary table
- Repeat until done
- Remove temporary id columns (optional)

Comment: The context is that for every customer there are a few orders and for each order there a few order details.  For each order there are a few notes.  For each order there are a few payments.  For each payment there are one to many notes.  Now imagine 50000 customers.  Having to commit for each parent key to be reserved is causing the process to run really slow.

Comment: What is the average to-insert-rowcount of your table with the most rows to insert per instance? Are we talking 100's, 10 000's?

Comment: the numbers you're describing look like they would benefit from the described approach. Seeing that you will also have to parse a bunch of CSV data I would consider SSIS, but I haven't worked with that since 2012 so I can't help you there.